# Make HTTP request via Javascript from within Qt

Tags: javascript, android, c++, qt, http

I am searching for a way to perform a raw POST/GET HTTP request with Javascript code and execute this script from within a Qt C++ application on Android and Desktop Linux, and of course, receive the result in the C++ application.

This is an example snippet of the functionality that I need which works in web browsers and in phantomjs:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://example.com/foo", false);
var datatype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
var data = "baz";
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", datatype);
xhr.send(data);
var some_object = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
var quintessence = do_something(some_object);
xhr.open("GET", "https://example.com/bar", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("foo", quintessence);
xhr.send(null);
var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

I am using the `XMLHttpRequest` class which is extremely easy to use, but not part of standard JS, so I can't really expect it to just be there. I don't care to do this in a different way, but something as easy would be nice. Also, the requests HAVE to be synchronous, since the post processing of the data is the main goal.

I guess a JIT capable Javascript implementation like V8 could at least execute Javascript code on all platforms, but that doesn't come with an HTTP request class out of the box.

The execution part can be done differently on Android and Desktop, but the same piece of code should always be executable on both platforms and do the same (or I would have to cut down the allowed syntax artificially somehow).

It seems like Android's WebView is not an option since it needs a context and can therefore not run in the background.

Anybody got an idea how to do this?

---

PS: Some functionality for headless browsing (more like the imperative approach of Java's HtmlUnit, less like the functional approach of phantomjs) via Javascript would be very very appreciated, but is not required at all.

Comment: Isn't there any way to do this ??